# SQL Query Join Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm currently stuck on a SQL query I'm trying to put together.

Here is the table layout:

---

### Table 1:

**tblUsers** *this table contains more columns, but not necessary in example*

- UserID (int)

**Sample Data:**

```
------
| ID |
------
| 1  |
------
| 2  |
------
```

---

### Table 2:

**tblColumns**

- ColumnID (int)
- ColumnName (nvarchar)

**Sample Data:**

```
--------------------
| ID | Column Name |
--------------------
| 1  | Name        |
--------------------
| 2  | Email       |
--------------------
| 3  | Age         |
--------------------
```

---

### Table 3:

**tblColumnData**

- ColumnDataID (int)
- UserID (int) (FK)
- ColumnID (int) (FK)
- ColumnDataContent (nvarchar)

**Sample Data:**

```
----------------------------------------------
| ID | UserID | ColumnID | ColumnDataContent |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1      | 1        | John Smith        |
----------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1      | 2        | john@email.com    |
----------------------------------------------
| 3  | 1      | 3        | 45                |
----------------------------------------------
| 4  | 2      | 2        | james@email.com   |
----------------------------------------------
| 5  | 2      | 3        | 30                |
----------------------------------------------
```

---

So you will see above, UserID:2 doesn't have a record in the tblColumnData table for ColumnID 1 which is the NAME column. I still need this to appear in the results even if it's NULL.

So I'm trying to get the data to return like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| UserID | ColumnID | ColumnName | ColumnDataContent |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 1        | Name       | John Smith        |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 2        | Email      | john@email.com    |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 3        | Age        | 45                |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | 1        | Name       | NULL or ''        |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | 2        | Email      | james@email.com   |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | 3        | Age        | 30                |
------------------------------------------------------
```

The select I have looks like this:

```
 SELECT cd.UserID,c.ColumnID,c.ColumnName,cd.ColumnDataContent 
 FROM tblColumns c 
      INNER JOIN tblColumnData cd ON c.ColumnID=cd.ColumnID
```

I have tried INNER, OUTER, LEFT.... etc all the different joins but with no success.

Hope someone can help :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please put sample data on a sqlfiddle.com

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Sameer: OP mention that *"I have tried INNER, OUTER, LEFT.... etc all the different joins but with no success"*

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: I couldn't do it in sqlfiddle as it's down at the moment.

Comment: @Aki: yes, seem like its not working at the moment

Comment: Can you show us your example with `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: The left join returns the exact same data as the inner join data I displayed in the result table in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would help you:

```
with userCTE as (
    select
        u.userId ,
            c.columnId
    from tblUsers as u
        cross join tblColumns as c
)

select 
    u.* ,
    Coalesce(cd.ColumnDatacontent, 'N/A') AS columnDataContent
from userCTE as u
    left join tblColumnData as cd
        on u.columnId = cd.columnId and u.userID = cd.userId
```

What you need else is to select which columns are interesting to you, this is only general sample how to get all needed rows.

Even more, you can use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` function to convert NULL values into more specific strings, if you need to.

Comment: tblUsers has 7 million records and the "userCTE" cross join seems to take forever. I added a WHERE clause which should reduces the tblColumns to 3 rows and tblUsers down to 500. I then should expect the result returned should be 1,500 records but it still does every possible combination in the table. In 4 seconds it returned 120,000 records, I stopped the query at this point :)

Comment: Wait, I tried it again with another WHERE, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Fiddle down we're all flying blind, but this is what I'd try first there if it were up.

```
SELECT tblUsers.UserID,
       tblColumns.ColumnID,
       tblColumns.ColumnName
       tblColumnData.ColumnDataContent
  FROM tblUsers,
       tblColumns
  LEFT JOIN tblColumnData  ON tblColumnData.ColumnID = tblColumns.ColumnID
                          AND tblColumnData.UserID   = tblUsers.UserID
;
```

You want the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) of Users and Columns, left joined to the Data table on ColumnID.

Comment: In a normal situation, the LEFT JOIN would do the trick but I'm just lost as to why it doesn't. Your example doesn't return what I need.

Comment: Yeah, I missed a join. Edited to add the join to user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a CROSS JOIN. I haven't tested this but it's a bit like this:

```
SELECT 
d.UserId
 ,d.ColumnId
,d.ColumnName
,d.ColumnDataContent
FROM tblColumns c 
CROSS JOIN tblusers u
LEFT join tblcolumndata d on d.columnid = c.columnid and d.userid = u.userid
```

Comment: I tried the CROSS JOIN but the query takes forever to run. I left it running for 25 seconds and it returned over 180,000 records!

Comment: Do your tables have indexes on the id fields? if not then you will want to add some.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CD.UserID,CD.ColumnID,t.ColumnName,CD.ColumnDataContent
from (select distinct u.UserID,c.ID,c.[ColumnName] tblUsers u
            cross join tblColumns c)t
left join tblColumnData CD on t.UserID=CD.UserID,t.ColumnID=CD.ColumnID
```

Comment: tblUsers has 7 million records and it looks like that cross join is causing some performance issues. Even with the a WHERE in place for a specific UserID, it was returning 19,088 :s

Comment: You have to use **`cross join`** in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it as per your example with no luck. This was my SQL on my real DB. 

SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT u.MailUserID,c.MLColumnID, c.MLColumnName FROM ss_tblMailUsers u
CROSS JOIN ss_tblMLColumns c
WHERE u.MailListID=28231) c
LEFT JOIN ss_tblMLColumnData CD ON c.MLColumnID=CD.MLColumnID